# Explain a few part of the code

Tags: javascript, html

I need somebody to explain how the code below resets the radio buttons to blank when you click "reset" at the bottom of the webpage

Any help would be appriciated, i am fairly new to javascript and HTML

here is a fiddle with it in - http://jsfiddle.net/jamiepollard28/sDLV4/8/

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Exam entry</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
window.validateForm=function() {
    var result = true;
    var msg = "";
    var focusname="";
    if (document.ExamEntry.name.value == "") {
        msg += "You must enter your name \n";
        focusname="name";
        //document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
        document.getElementById('name1').style.color = "red";
        //result = false;
    }
    if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value == "") {
        msg += "You must enter the subject \n";
       // document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
        if (focusname=="")
        {
        focusname="subject";
        }
        document.getElementById('subject1').style.color = "red";
        //result = false;
    }
    var Number = document.ExamEntry.Exam_Number.value
    if (Number == "") {
        msg += "You must enter the exam Number \n";
        //document.ExamEntry.Exam_Number.focus();
        if (focusname=="")
        {
        focusname="Exam_Number";
        }
        document.getElementById('Exam_Number1').style.color = "red";
        //result = false;
    }else if (Number.length != 4) {
        msg += "You must enter at least Four Numbers in the Exam Number \n";
         if (focusname=="")
        {
        focusname="Exam_Number";
        }
        //document.ExamEntry.Exam_Number.focus();
        document.getElementById('Exam_Number1').style.color = "red";
        //result = false;
    }
else if (isNaN(Number)) {
        msg += "You must enter at least four numeric characters in the Exam Number feild \n";
     if (focusname=="")
        {
        focusname="Exam_Number";
        }   
    // document.ExamEntry.Exam_Number.focus();
        document.getElementById('Exam_Number1').style.color = "red";
        //result = false;
    }
    var valchecked = '';
    var len = document.getElementsByName('examtype').length;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

if ( document.ExamEntry.examtype[i].checked ) {

valchecked = document.ExamEntry.examtype[i].value;
 break;

}

}
    if (valchecked == '') {
        msg += "Select Exam Type";
        document.getElementById('Exam_Type').style.color = "red";
         if (focusname=="")
        {
        focusname="examtype_GCSE";
        }

    } 

    if (msg != ""){
        alert(msg)
        document.getElementById(focusname).focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        return confirm('You have chosen ' + valchecked + ' is this correct?');
    }

}
}//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
<table width="50%" border="0">
<tr>
<td id="name1">Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name"  id="name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="subject1">Subject</td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="Exam_Number1">Exam Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Exam_Number" id="Exam_Number" ><font size="3">(Maximum characters: 4)</font> </td>
</tr>
<tr>

<table><form action="">
<td id="Exam_Type">Exam Type</td>
<tr><td><input type="radio" id="examtype_GCSE" name="examtype" value="GCSE" /> : GCSE<br /></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" id="examtype_AS" name="examtype" value="AS"/> : AS<br /></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" id="examtype_A2" name="examtype" value="A2" /> : A2<br /></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
<td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: It's not the code. It's an `<input type="reset">`. The browser simply knows what to do with that.

Answer (score 3):

The `<input type="reset" />` is a built in feature of HTML forms. It will simply clear or form fields and set other controls back to their defaults.

Answer (score 0):

You are using . This type of input is a ready made function in html that just makes the complete form blank with only one click.

http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms13.htm

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="reset" />` will simply clear all input values

It is simply a Reset from button and is a built in feature

Answer (score 0):

the property of reset button is to set all the value to blank as you made at time of the creation of page .it does not contain the values filled at the time of filling of form by the user,and in the case of a radio button, if you put any parameter like checked /unchecked then it will reset it to that condition.

```
     <input type="radio" checked />
```

and  reset will clear all the form elements just like the built in property of submit is to submit the form and reset is set revised again .

```
   <input type="reset"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

The Reset object represents a reset button in an HTML form.

Clicking on a reset button resets all controls within the form to their default values.

For each  tag in an HTML form, a Reset object is created.

Clicking on a reset button fires the onreset event!